# Javascript Computation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

Hi just want to ask on how can I get the answer here? I get NaN tho I tried to put parseFloat for each variable. also, if the user chooses NO from the radio box, the value for the next question would be zero. Thanks for the great help!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[name=q-1], input[name=q-2], input[name=q-4], input[name=q-6]").change(function(e) {

        var $row = $(this).parent();
        var cooling_area_sqm = $row.find("input[name=q-1]").val();
        var people = $row.find("input[name=q-2]").val();
        var glass_walls_m = $row.find("input[name=q-4]").val();
        var ceiling_m = $row.find("input[name=q-6]").val();

        var sqm_tr = 18;
        var sqm_tr_hp = 1.25;
        var heat_gain = 0.3;
        var solar_penetration = 0.2;
        var ceiling_height = 1.1;

        var mTons = 0;
        var mHP = 0;
        var mHeatGainHP = 0;
        var mGlassWallsHP = 0;
        var mCeilingHP = 0;
        var temp_var = 0;

            mTons = parseFloat(mTons);
            mHP = parseFloat(mHP);
            mHeatGainHP = parseFloat(mHeatGainHP);
            mGlassWallsHP = parseFloat(mGlassWallsHP);
            mCeilingHP = parseFloat(mCeilingHP);

            mTons = cooling_area_sqm / sqm_tr;
            <!-- start of error -->
                            mHP = mTons * sqm_tr_hp;
            mHeatGainHP = (people * heat_gain) / 10;
            mHP = mHP + (mHP * mHeatGainHP);
            mGlassWallsHP = glass_walls_m * solar_penetration;
            mHP = mHP + mGlassWallsHP;
            mCeilingHP = ceiling_m * ceiling_height;
            mHP = mHP * mCeilingHP;

        $(".capacity").val(mHP);

        <!-- end of error -->
    });
});
</script>
<form method="post">
<ol>
    <li>
        <label>Question?</label><br/>
        <input class="input-text q-input" type="text" name="q-1" value="<?php echo $cooling_area_sqm; ?>"/>&nbsp;sqm
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>Question?</label><br/>
        <input class="input-text q-input" type="text" name="q-2" value="<?php echo $people; ?>"/>&nbsp;people
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>Question?</label><br/>
        <input type="radio" name="q-3" value="yes-3"/>&nbsp;Yes
        <br/>
        <input type="radio" name="q-3" value="no-3"/>&nbsp;No
        <br/>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>Question?</label><br/>
        <input class="input-text q-input" type="text" name="q-4" value="<?php echo $glass_walls_m; ?>"/>&nbsp;meter/s
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>Question?</label><br/>
        <input type="radio" name="q-5" value="yes-5"/>&nbsp;Yes
        <br/>
        <input type="radio" name="q-5" value="no-5"/>&nbsp;No
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>Question?</label><br/>
        <input class="input-text q-input" type="text" name="q-6" value="<?php echo $ceiling_m; ?>"/>&nbsp;meter/s
        <div class="add-info">
            example: 4 meters + 1 meter more
        </div>
    </li>
</ol>
</form>

<div class="capacity-cont">
<label>Question?</label><br/>
<input class="input-text q-input capacity" type="text" name="c-7" disabled />&nbsp;HP
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Uk5bN/

Comment: Where do you get NAN?

Comment: I get it from the mHP variable.

Comment: @user3234055, please reduce your code to the minimum required to reproduce your problem. It's a bit long as-is. Also, state exactly which line produces the error (some debugging might help there...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's other things I would change, but minimally do:

```
var $row = $(this).closest('form');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Uk5bN/1/

When you're doing `$row = $(this).parent()`, you're getting the `li`, which is a peer and not a parent to the other `li`s which contain the fields you're trying to `$.find()`. `form` is above all of the `input`s you're trying to select for.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that parseFloat("") == NaN. It only takes one operand to be empty to screw your calculations.